# I'm getting an attribute error using tensorflow

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and this code is for object detection, it works fine on my webcam but has an error when using an external camera
This is what I have:

```
for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
        cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
```

Here's the message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/byeo9/PycharmProjects/FYP-ENV/Testing 2.py", line 31, in <module>
    for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Comment: You're using a tuple when it should be a numpy array. Could you include what classIds and confs are?

Comment: classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=0.5) Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: I mean their output. But if you want to flatten them you have to convert them to numpy arrays first which can be done using np.asarray().